# associative compositions w/ this criteria have a neutral element

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\Delta$ is an associative composition on $E$ and if there is an element $u$ of $E$ | ∀$a\in E$  $∃$ $x,y\in E$ satisfying $u\Delta x=a=y\Delta u$, then ∃ a neutral element for $\Delta$

Answer (score 0):

∀$a\in E$ we can find $x,y\in E$ satisfying $u\Delta x=a$. So we pick $z\in E$ | $z\Delta u=u$.

Now, we left-multiply $u\Delta x=a$ by $z$ $\Longrightarrow$ $(z\Delta u)\Delta x=z\Delta a$ $\Longrightarrow$ $u\Delta x=z\Delta a$ $\Longrightarrow$ $a=z\Delta a$.

Note that we just established $z$ as a left neutral(identity) for $\Delta$.

Now, ∀$a\in E$ we can find $x,y\in E$ satisfying $ y\Delta u=a$. Pick $q\in E$ | $u\Delta q=u$

$ y\Delta u=a$ $\Longrightarrow$ $y\Delta (u\Delta q)=a\Delta q$ $\Longrightarrow$ $y\Delta a=a\Delta q$ $\Longrightarrow$ $a=a\Delta q$

∴ $q$ is a right neutral for $\Delta$.

Since $\Delta$ has a right and left neutral it follows that it has a neutral element, $z=q$.

Comment: If you knew the answer, why ask the question?

Comment: oh that is to keep track of my work. To encourage me to make sure it is right. To share in case others need help. It motivates me to be thorough...

Comment: Please do not use this site as your personal notepad. If you feel a question and its answer will be particularly interesting to others, you can do something like this (but please let it be really unusual). But at least mention in the question that this is why you post it.

Comment: Actually the site itself has the mechanism to answer your own question. Therefore, I will continue to do so as long as I please.

Comment: Ok, and I will start downvoting your self-answers when I see them. The fact that the site has this functionality does not mean it is encouraged.

Comment: I too have the right to downvote.

Comment: You certainly do.

Comment: And also I will report any form of harassment from you. So keep it up.

Comment: Don't worry, I will not harrass you. I will just downvote questions and answers I feel should not be on this site, regardsless of whether they are from you. I happen to not think the sort of question/answer pairs you give here belong on the site.

Comment: Ok Toby, see you on the battlefield.

Comment: @VladimirLouis This is not a batterfield. If you thibnk it is your seeing the site from a wrong point of view. Just keep attention, is not matter of tastes, I strongly agree with Tobias, if you think is usefull for your progresses to do it you should say it clearly in the question.

Comment: ok no problem. I agree too. But, I did like like the way he approached me. You have read the exchanges and deduced that I started it? All I want is the inspiration and to learn and share with fellow math lovers. From what I remember in school you guys are seldom social creatures and pedantic to a fault. Keep the rigor out of life and in mathematics where it belongs. I will make the necessary tweaks to my questions, but I will continue to share.

Comment: Seems that you contine to miss the point @VladimirLouis. Here is not matter of you adn me or of the "seldom social creatures". The question is that this site is not mine and is not your. If site was mine I'd change some rules that I don't like but is is NOT!

So stop to think it is a personal problem.
With Regard.

Comment: If the site does not belong to any of us, why lose our cool over how a user is "legally" using the site? 'Live and let live'. I dont mind when someone makes a recommendation to me, but to DEMAND that I behave according to your likings does not sit well with me. Am all for peace, but the site allows me to answer my own questions that should be enough to let you know you are way out of line. Believe I do not want to war with math lovers or anyone for that matter. So olive branch?